# An 'iff' property involving a measurable set $E$, an open set $Q$ and a closed set $F$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm having a hard time proving the following:

Show that a set $E$ is measurable iff for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closet set $F$ and an open set $Q$ for which $F \subseteq E \subseteq Q$ and $m^*(Q\setminus F) < \epsilon$

Comment: What do you mean by $P$ ?

Comment: I just fixed it, I meant Q instead of P.  I tend to use Q or P for "open sets" because O reminds me too much of zero.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, I think we can assume it's in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I'm stuck with the existence part of it.  I'm not sure how to justify that such an open set and such a closed set exist.

Comment: This smells like a Royden question. At any rate, your book should have a proof for equivalency of measurability of $E$ with the existence of an open set $Q$ for each $\epsilon > 0$ containing $E$ st $m^*(Q-E)< \epsilon$ and likewise an equivalency statement for contained closed sets $F$ for each $\epsilon.$ Your answer should modify this proof to fit the statement of your problem (start with assuming $E$ is measurable and finite in measure and use excision and compliments).

Answer (score 3):

A set $E$ is **measurable** if for every $A\subset X$
\begin{align}
m^\ast(A) = m^\ast(E\cap A) +m^\ast(E^c\cap A). 
\end{align}
Since $m^\ast$ is an outer measure, then trivially we have
\begin{align}
m^\ast(A)\leq m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E^c\cap A).
\end{align}
Thus, all we need to do is prove the reverse inequality, that is
\begin{align}
m^\ast(A)\geq m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E^c\cap A).
\end{align}

Let give ourselves a little room, i.e. it suffices to prove
\begin{align}
m^\ast(A)+\epsilon\geq m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E^c\cap A)
\end{align}
for every fixed $\epsilon>0$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $F\subset E \subset Q$ such that $m^\ast(Q\backslash F)<\epsilon$ where $F$ is closed and $Q$ is open. In particular, it also follows that $F^c\supset E^c \supset Q^c$.

Now, observe
\begin{align}
m^\ast(E\cap A) + m^\ast(E^c\cap A) \leq&\ m^\ast(Q\cap A) + m^\ast(F^c\cap A)\\ 
\leq&\ m^\ast(F\cap A)+m^\ast((Q\backslash F) \cap A)+(F^c\cap A)\\
\leq&\ m^\ast(F\cap A)+m(F^c\cap A)+m^\ast(Q\backslash F)\\
\leq&\ m^\ast(A) + \epsilon
\end{align} 
since $F$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $E$ is measurable and finite. Then for each $\frac{\epsilon}{2},$ there is a collection of open intervals $Q\bigcup\limits_k I_k$ such that $\sum\limits_k l(I_k)-m^*(E)< \frac{epsilon}{2}.$ Likewise, since the complement of $E$ is infinite, there is a partition $E^c = \bigcup\limits_k E_k^c$ with $E_k^c$ measurable and finite. Thus for each $E_k^c$ there is an countable open collection of intervals $J_k$ covering $E_k^c$ within $\frac{\epsilon}{2*2^k}$ of $m^*(E^c_k.)$ Union them together for an open set $F^c$ that covers $E^c$ within $\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Taking compliments, we have a finite closed set $F$ contained in $E$ whose distance from $Q$ is $\epsilon,$ that is, $m^*(Q-F)<\epsilon.$

For the infinite case just break $E$ apart into a measurable partition with finite components and repeat the above for each component to get an open set $Q_i$ and closed set $F_i$ within $\frac{\epsilon}{2^m}$ of each other. Take unions.

For the other direction, construct an $F_\alpha$ and $G_\delta$ set and a measure zero set all from the $m^*(Q-F)<\epsilon$ property. Express $E$ as unions, intersections, and/or complements of these sets. Conclude.